# Data set- not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I have declared a dataset publicly in my class this is the code

```
public DataSet GetUsersDataSet()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELCT * FROM login", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            con.Open(); 
            da.Fill(ds, "login");
            return ds;

        }

        catch 
        { 
            new ApplicationException("Data Error:");

        }
        finally { con.Close(); }


    }
```

But its giving me error:

> WebApplication1.classes.LoginDB.GetUsersDataSet()': not all code paths
>   return a value.

But in my code `ds` is returning , I have tried after removing the try catch that time its fine. Can any one tell what was the mistake.?

Comment: your return needs to be outside of try and catch

Comment: Just add a return in your catch block

Comment: Sometimes developers should forget that they are humans. If you were compiler how would you decide what to return when exception occurs in `try` block? BTW, you need to throw `ApplicationException`. not just create an instance

Comment: @user2063626 That would still fail.

Comment: @Vijesh you must return your result after finally block.

Comment: @PLB your correct I just trying only.. :-)

Comment: @DGibbs nope, it won't fail. But doing that is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if the `try` fails? You need a `return` statement outside of the `try/catch` block.

```
public DataSet GetUsersDataSet()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELCT * FROM login", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        con.Open(); 
        da.Fill(ds, "login");
    }
    catch 
    { 
        new ApplicationException("Data Error:");
    }
    finally { con.Close(); }

    return ds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your method return type is `DataSet`, you should return also outside of the `try/catch` statement because your `try` block might fail. If it is fail, your method doesn't return any value. That's why you are getting this error. You can use it like;

```
public DataSet GetUsersDataSet()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELCT * FROM login", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        con.Open(); 
        da.Fill(ds, "login");

    }

    catch 
    { 
        new ApplicationException("Data Error:");

    }
    finally { con.Close(); }

    return ds;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just imagine if you got an exception, you are not returning any thing in catch block. so 
add return end of the try catch block. use a single return instead of multiple returns.

```
try
{
   con.Open(); 
    da.Fill(ds, "login");

 }
catch
{
    new ApplicationException("Data Error:");

}
return ds;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return a `dataset`.The returned dataset should be outside try-catch statement..

```
public DataSet GetUsersDataSet()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELCT * FROM login", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        con.Open(); 
        da.Fill(ds, "login");


    }

    catch 
    { 
        new ApplicationException("Data Error:");

    }
    finally { con.Close(); }

    return ds;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the method does not [return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx) a `DataSet`(f.e. if `da.Fill` throws an exception), but that's the contract of a `return` statement.

You can ensure it by moving the `return` to outside of the `try-catch`:

```
public DataSet GetUsersDataSet()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // ...
    try{
        // ...
    }
    catch{ 
        //...
    }
    finally{ 
        //...
    }
    return ds;
}
```

C# Specs:

> 8.9.4 The return statement returns control to the caller of the function member in which the return statement appears.

//...

> If the return statement is enclosed by one or more try blocks with associated finally blocks, control is initially transferred to the finally block of the innermost try statement. When and if control reaches the end point of a finally block, control is transferred to the finally block of the next enclosing try statement. This process is repeated until the finally blocks of all enclosing try statements have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to throw the exception you created on the catch. That should fix your problem.

Check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to re-throw exception when database operation fails:

```
public DataSet GetUsersDataSet()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELCT * FROM login", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        con.Open(); 
        da.Fill(ds, "login");
        return ds;

    }
    catch 
    { 
       throw new ApplicationException("Data Error:");

    }
    finally { con.Close(); }
}
```

So if exception will be thrown in `try` block `ApplicationException` will be re-thrown after `finally` block closes connection.

If I am mistaken and this is not what you want. `new ApplicationException("Data Error:");` does not do anything in your `catch` block but creating new instance of `ApplicationException` so you should remove it.

Comment: So what was the better way.? is this is correct catch(Exception ex){lblError.text = ex.message.toString();}  or a custom message in catch.?

Comment: @Vijesh You should never catch all exceptions and mute them. If you have to catch all exceptions (i.e. your example.) you should always re-throw them. When you're re-throwing different exception always add caught exception as `InnerException`. Also there's nothing wrong with returning empty dataset until you want to display exactly what happened.